# Chrome Extension Status From C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome-extension, windows-services

I am working with a background service in C#, to verify that a particular chrome extension is installed an active.

We can get installed extensions information by reading manifest.json file from "%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions"

But how to get the **status of extension** either it's active or not.

This is a windows service so I am working with C# and avoiding JavaScript API's for chrome.

Answer (score 0):

I thing is there no way to observe any file system which you are have mentions above.

we can do using this fallowing way
1. Manage some flag variable in text file for track status of chrome ext using this API. https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_codelab_filesystem
2. change the flag variable using enable/disable event using this API
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management#event-onEnabled
3.read the text file, in file system using C#.

Comment: So far that's the only solution let see if I can do this. Will let you know shortly

Comment: @Bilal if you cant do this one let me know i will help you to do this

Comment: Thank you so much @Pankaj I am not able to do this...! but my extension developer has made some changes he is posting a secret URL on the network tab of chrome if the extension is active.

Comment: Now I don't know how to read that information from chrome request :/

Comment: this way is quite complex.